# Nothing Happens When I Want to Get JSON From a Restful Web Service

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, web-services

I have trying to get a JSON file from a Restful webservice. I wrote a code that you can see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
        
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            function loadDoc() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=5.39&lat=51.57", false);
                xhttp.send();
                var r = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                var m = r.geometry.type;
                window.alert(m);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For this scenario the code is running without any exception.

But when I try to get a JSON file from different URL it doesn't work.
One of the URLs I tried is "weather api" and I modified the part of my code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
        
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            function loadDoc() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22", false);
                xhttp.send();
                var r = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                var m = r.coord.lon;
                window.alert(m);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And other URL is under my localhost (my goal is actually get JSON from my local restful webservice). This url is "10.10.10.190:8080/ngram/webapi/user". When I request this URL via any browser I get static JSON file which is `{"username":"xxxx","password":"xxxx"}`.

Again I modified the code like this:

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://10.10.10.190:8080/ngram/webapi/user", false);
    xhttp.send();
    var r = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    var m = r.username;
    window.alert(m);
}
```

But in both of these cases I didn't get any response. I am stuck in there.

**Edit: When i look at developer tools i see error like this:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjeV4.png)

By the way for my Tomcat web.xml i added this lines:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you check your `developer console => network tab` and confirm whether the call went fine?

Comment: A word of warning, I would avoid using `async:false`,  because even if you get this code to work, it's going to fail in the future as it's been depreciated on the main thread.

Comment: I doubt you got no response _at all_...maybe nothing appeared on screen, but I think you just aren't doing any debugging. Do you know how to use your browser's developer tools to watch what is happening with your request?

Comment: This error may be caused due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. So try running your app with the real server.

Comment: Sometimes the fix can be as easy as changing URL prefix from `http` to `https`

Comment: @UllasHunka that's pure speculation. We don't know under what conditions the page is running or what response is coming back. Better to wait for OP to give some useful info than make random suggestions, which might lead the OP down an irrelevant track.

Comment: @Alex that's pure speculation. We don't know whether the URL is correct or not, or what response is coming back. Better to wait for OP to give some useful info than make random suggestions, which might lead the OP down an irrelevant track.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I'm `postulating` and not stating. :)

Comment: I'm close to solving problem. I guess problem comes from Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. I got an error and you can see in my main post, i shared with you. For Chrome, if i add an extension which is calling CORS and after that run my application, everything looks fine. I can reach my goal. So somehow, i guess, i must allow for COSR and i've already research on that but i couldn't make it.